# Click and Drag not working with jQuery UI iframeFix in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

This is a bit hard to explain, so I've set up a reduced test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z6h6/1/. Essentially what's happening is I'm passing jQuery UI's `.draggable` to the content of the iFrame, and using jQuery UI's built-in iframeFix to avoid issues with the iFrame capturing the mouse events.

This works great, except in Firefox, where clicking and dragging no longer seems to work; instead, you have to click, release, then drag, then click again to place. Is this expected behavior? Is there a way around this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is to flick off the iframe at the start of the mousedown:

```
$iframe.css('display', 'none');
```

then set up draggable and trigger event:

```
$draggable.trigger(event);
```

then show iframe again:

```
$iframe.css('display', 'block');
```

The function should run fast enough so you shouldn't see any flicker - took me trial and error to find this but this fixes the iframe issue in Firefox I had.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Firefox Version and check this again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm using FF 13, and confirmed the same in FF 12, 11, and 10 on both Mac OS X and Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a long time to figure out, and the solution posted here didn't work, and it still seems to be an issue in jQuery.

The problem is that in Firefox, it appears that the mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove events do not bubble from the iframe up to the parent document.

The workaround I used is this:

```
// From parent document
// Get iframe 'document'
var $iframe = $('iframe').$el.content();

// Then bind listeners for events, and trigger them on parent document
$iframe.on({
    mousemove: function(e){
        $(document).trigger(e);
    },
    mousedown: function (e) {
        $(document).trigger(e);
    },
    mouseup: function (e) {
        $(document).trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Hopefully this saves people some time.